# Python: How to load a JSON string bigger than 1GB

Tags: python, json

We get a lot of files coming from the eBay API and they are all "1 line JSON string".

MOST(99%) of these files have a size less than 1GB
Sometimes 1 of the file will be bigger than  1 GB and in that case the regular ***json.loads()*** function that I have used till now will crash the execution of the script and output the simple "Killed" message on the stdout.

For example, this basic line of code

```
dlist = json.loads(big_string)
```

will crash.
I tried bigjson.load(filename), but bigjson takes over and does not return a JSON object, it will return a bigjson object instead and everything inside that data structure will also become a bigjson object...
My algorithm needs dict and list and so I cannot use bigjson.

What can I use to load a JSON String(not file) that is bigger than 1 GB

(I use python version 3.8)

Comment: There are other streaming JSON readers but whether that will work also depends on your application. If you want to loop over internal objects in a list then reading each list item separately would be feasible, but if you really need all of the data in memory, you just need enough memory. I understand Pandas can make working with large data sets more pleasant, but there are limits to how much it can do, too.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to work with 8GB of JSON data and I tried using following two solutions and in the end went with second solution

1. you can try  [ijson](https://github.com/ICRAR/ijson) module for loading large files
2. you can use mongodb to load JSON file and then use pymongo to retrieve data in python it will be in python dict and is similar to JSON and will work with pandas as well

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried ijson for several hours and I have no success. Imagine my WHOLE Json string/file-content to be: "{"categoryTreeId":"0","categoryTreeVersion":"127","categoryAspects":[1,2,3]}"
How would you use ijson to retrieve the list [1,2,3] ?

Comment: i think this might work
`with open('json.json',mode='r') as file:`
      `items=ijson.items(file, 'categoryAspects.item')`

items will be a list try and let me know

Comment: After so many tries, I now got the syntax right but ijson will crash if the file being loaded is over 1GB . Also not sure about  deploying mongoDB just for reading 1 file, sounds like an overkill to me. There should be a package out there that will not crash when we load file over 1GB.

Comment: why not try once for your data file? ijson have a different mechanism of parsing and is built to deal with larger data files. It will not read and parse whole file at once so it should work

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "try once for your data file", I tried several times not just once and every time ijson will fail and crash and get killed...
There must be another package or tool out there that can help me load that 2GB json string into a Python object.  Has to exist!!!